# Custom List .Remove

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Heyo. First of all, I'm sorry if I'm asking something that's really simple. It's been holding me up for a day or two and I can't find any tutorials that cover what it is I'm trying to do.

I have a set of cubes that have to hold some game objects, along with an int that displays how important that object is and where it will appear in something called the Resolution Order. That bit is all working fine.

The CubeContents class:

```
public class CubeContents : IComparable<CubeContents>{
public GameObject objectType;
public int resolutionOrder;

public CubeContents (GameObject name, int importance){
    objectType = name;
    resolutionOrder = importance;
}


public int CompareTo(CubeContents other){
    if(other == null)
        return 1;
    return resolutionOrder - other.resolutionOrder;
}
```

The method I'm using passes the specific game object to cube and uses this code to add it to the array:

```
public void newArrival(GameObject incoming){
    int importance = discoverImportanceOfObject (incoming);
    thisContents.Add (new CubeContents (incoming, importance));
    thisContents.Sort ();
```

}

discoverImportanceOfObject is basically a long list of "else if" statements that returns a number I'm using to order these things. The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to remove this object from the array before I destroy it. This piece of code basically seems totally non responsive, but it compiles and runs just fine. No odd error messages, nothing.

```
public void leavingObject(GameObject leaving){
    int importance = discoverImportanceOfObject (leaving);
    thisContents.Remove (new CubeContents (leaving, importance)));
    thisContents.TrimExcess ();
}
```

I'm at a total loss as to why this is. I've tried all sorts of things (IndexOf, then a RemoveAt, nulling out the entire array and then rebuilding it based on colliders...)

This just *feels* like it'll be a simple fix that I'm completely overlooking, but as I don't have an error message to search, or any other sort of jumping off point, I'm a bit stuck...

Comment: You are removing an object that doesn't exist (you are creating a new one in the remove method). It doesn't match based on property values, it matches based on physical references. In order to use the remove, you need to find the **actual** object and remove it.

Comment: You either need to implement IEquatable or override object.equals to use it like you are.

Comment: in your `CompareTo` method, it might be better to do this in your last line: `return resolutionOrder.CompareTo(other.resolutionOrder);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This object will not exist...

```
thisContents.Remove (new CubeContents (leaving, importance)));
```

Instead, loop through the thisContents collection to find the object matching the 'leaving' and 'importance'. Then remove that object.

Comment: I... Don't have much to say.

Thank you :D